# Files needed in android app, where to store them? Asset folder? SD Card?

Tags: pdf, directory, where-clause, store, assets

I'm creating an app that holds a lot of pdf files, i'm confused where to store those files,in asset folder? or somewhere else and please mention in your answer where the files can be kept, so when app installed, the files can be accessed.

Considering i'm going to display those files too.

Comment: Depends on the amount of data all your PDF files have, and if they will be modified/changed after install or not

Comment: @AndréSchild It won't be modified, i just need to read them using PdfRenderer Class Of API 21 (above).